# Apache POI hslf missing from release 3.13?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm trying to make an PPT(X) presentation from java code. I've downloaded apache poi 3.13 release from [official site](https://poi.apache.org/download.html). I've added a binary to my class path and now when I'm trying to create a presentation - it fails to compile.

It seems like package referenced

```
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model;
```

is not found. However,

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
```

is working fine and I able to create an Excel spreadsheet file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
 <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
 <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>
```

or just "poi" as artifactId? I had the same issue and changing the dependency solved the issue.

Comment: I'm not using maven, just downloaded the binary and added to build path.

Comment: Nevertheless, make sure you also have poi-ooxml-3.13.jar and poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13.jar. Not not only poi-3.13.jar

Comment: Thank you very much! I added only poi-3.13 from downloaded artifacts. Adding poi-ooxml-3.13 solved the problem!

Comment: poi-ooxml is needed because of the new format of the .___x MS files. Apache should me more clear about that

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the cunningly titled [Apache POI Components Map](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), in order to use `HSLF` you need both the core POI jar *and* the POI Scratchpad jar

If using Maven, you'd add a dependency of

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
  <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>
```

(Or add one on the OOXML component, that'll currently pull the scratchpad in too)

If you're using the [Apache POI binary download](http://poi.apache.org/download.html), add both the `poi-#.###.jar` file and the `poi-scratchpad-#.###.jar` file to your classpath

Comment: Additional be aware since the advent of "common sl" - since POI 3.13 - quite a few hslf class names have been changed. So SlideShow is now an interface and the implementation is called HSLFSlideShow.